# get/set for all available properties (JS)

Tags: javascript, oop

Is it possible to create get/set function for undefined properties,
like in PHP __get() and __set() ?

Answer (score 2):

You can access JavaScript object properties values using array access notation, you can also create a new property at any time using this notation or regular assignment notation.

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.Name = "Luis";
alert(myObject.Name);
alert(myObject["Name"]);
myObject["Name"] = "Dany";
alert(myObject.Name);
```

Comment: Also note, that if you access an undefined property, it just returns `undefined`. `(myObject[Math.random()] === undefined) === !(Math.random() in myObject) // true`

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
function ClassName(arg) {
    var v = arg;
    this.getter = function {
         return v;
    };
    this.setter = function(val) {
         v = val;
    };
}
```

when you use it

```
var cn = new ClassName('a');
cn.setter('b');
alert(cn.getter()); /* alerts value 'b' */
```

Note that this uses the Constructor Invocation Pattern. By convention, you need to declare the function/class name with capital letter to indicate that this function/class need to be declared with the 'new' keyword.
Hope this helps